# Swift Package Manager: add compile flag to a single file -fno-objc-arc

Tags: c++, swift, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c++, swift-package-manager

**Overview**

I'm porting an C++ / ObjC++ library to Swift Package Manager. The library targets common Apple platforms (iOS, macOS). Currently, the library can be built using `xcodebuild` and a static library target.

**Question**

Since the library contains C++ <> ObjC bridging code, it has **one file** compiled with the flag `-fno-objc-arc`. All of the other files are compiled with ARC. Is it possible to pass a flag telling SPM to also compile that file without ARC?

**Screenshot**

[image: screenshot]

**Package.swift**

```
// swift-tools-version:5.4
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "library_name",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "library_name",
            targets: ["library_name"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "library_name",
            dependencies: [],
            path: "./sources/",
            exclude: [

            ],
            sources:
                [
                    "sourcefile_noARC.mm",
                    "sourcefile2.mm",
                    "sourcefile3.cpp",
                ],
            publicHeadersPath: "SwiftPackage/headers/",
            cxxSettings: [
                .headerSearchPath("./")
            ]
        ),
    ],
    cxxLanguageStandard: .cxx14
)
```

**"Unsafe Flags"**

I've tried using [unsafe flags](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/cxxsetting/3112675-unsafeflags) feature to pass the compile flag to the whole library:

```
.target(
            name: "fs_helpers",
            dependencies: [],
            path: "./sources/",
            exclude: [

            ],
            sources:
                [
                    "sourcefile_noARC.mm",
                    "sourcefile2.mm",
                    "sourcefile3.cpp",
                ],
            publicHeadersPath: "SwiftPackage/headers/",
            cxxSettings: [
                .headerSearchPath("./"),
                .unsafeFlags(["-fno-objc-arc"]) // ADDING THE FLAG
            ]
        ),
```

However, this adds the flag to the whole library and not just to a single file as I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is not possible at the moment. Yet we have a hope that [this proposal](https://forums.swift.org/t/draft-proposal-target-specific-build-settings/18031/48) will be accepted and your (and mine) problem will be solved. There are few alternatives that may help:

1. Use Cocoa pods
2. Use submodules
3. Use precompiled binary

Comment: Hasn't that proposal been already accepted? I'm actually using the `unsafeFlags` feature, which gives me an error when I try to integrate this `library_name` to another library.